# PyCharm - Keyboard shortcut for markdown preview tab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea, pycharm

In PyCharm when I create a markdown file (`*.md`), I have two tabs at the bottom of the file pane/window: `Text` and `Preview`.

Is there a way I can assign a keyboard shortcut to switch to the preview tab? Or to switch between the two tabs?

Edit: (Screeshot)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcuts is already assigned: <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Rigth Arrow</kbd> for switching on right tab and same for left with <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>

Comment: Can you tell me what is the shortcut name I should search for in the keymap editor? I might have reassigned those shortcuts.

Comment: @eyalev shortcut name: `Select Next Tab in multi-editor file`